# Предупреждение C26451. Арифметическое переполнение

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2019, индексация

Столкнулся с предупреждением при попытке получить элемент вектора по индексу с использованием вычисляемого значения.

> Предупреждение    C26451  Арифметическое переполнение: использование оператора "+" на байтовом значении 4 и приведение результата к байтовому значению 8. Приведите значение к более широкому типу перед вызовом оператора "+", чтобы избежать переполнения (io.2).

Пример кода, в котором наблюдается предупреждение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a{0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int b = 0;
    std::cout << a[b + 1] << std::endl;  // подчеркивает 'b+1'
    return 0;
}
```

**Почему возникает такое предупреждение?**

В моем понимании переполнение - попытка записать в переменную значение большее, чем выделяемая на переменную память.

Я бы понял это предупреждение тут:

```
unsigned char c = 24;
c += 250;
```

Но в данном примере IDE не видит проблемы.

**В чем я заблуждаюсь с определением переполнения?**

Также заметил, что изменение платформы в диспетчере конфигурации VS2019 с x64 на x86 приводит к исчезновению этого предупреждения.

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/) *"Но в данном примере IDE не видит проблемы."* - порождает warning C4305 https://godbolt.org/z/97rqvs4ad Видимо у вас выключены предупреждения. Вообще, в обоих случаях имеется ошибка неявного преобразования типов, о которой не сообщается.

Comment: @user7860670 откорректировал пример (257 заменил на 250), при значении <=255 предупреждений нет. Хотя фактически переполнение происходит.

Comment: Вместо модификации второго примера стоило бы добавить третий, а то мой предыдущий комментарий становится кривым... Переполнения во втором случае не происходит ни так, ни так. Там происходит двойное неявное преобразование, причем второе с *потенциальным* усечением значения. Причем в оригинальном примере это усечение было не потенциальное, а неизбежное, на что компилятор и вдал C4305. Заметьте, что С/C++ по неведомым причинам не поддерживают арифметических операций на типами меньше `int`, поэтому `c += 250;` эквивалентно `c = static_cast<unsigned char>(static_cast<int>(c) + 250);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае суть [предупреждения](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26451?view=msvc-170) в следующем: для индексации вектора на 64 битной платформе используется 64 битное беззнаковое целое, но выражение "b+1" имеет тип int. Если предположить, что в b будет максимальное значение, представимое типом int, то получим UB. Решение: привести хотя бы один из операндов к 64 битному типу.

Компилятор ругается здесь не на конкретные значения, а на типы, используемые в выражении.